# Integral equation of the form $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a t^4} g(x,t) dt = e^{-b x^4}$

Tags: functional-analysis, integral-equations

How to solve an integral equation of the following form
\begin{align} 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a t^4}  g(x,t) dt = e^{-b x^4}
\end{align}
where $a$ and $b$ are some positive constants.

I am not very familiar with this subject any suggestions you might have would be great.

Comment: Well, $g(x,t) = \delta\left(t - {\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}^{1/4} x\right)$ works.

Comment: Are there any restrictions for $g (x,t)$ or conditions it should meet?

Comment: There are plenty of solutions, since the RHS is not a function of $a$. In the oppositecase, things get interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform

Comment: One class of solutions is to take $g(x,t)=h(x)f(t)$. Any $f$ that makes the integral convergent (and nonzero) gives an easy equation for $h$.

Comment: @YuriyS I would like $g(x,t)$ to be continuous.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Are you suggesting I take Laplace transform of both sides?

Comment: @JohnBarber are there any solutions in terms of continuous functions?

Comment: @Boby: as already said, this problem makes little sense, there are too many solutions. However, *if* the RHS were a function of $a$, we might read the LHS as a Laplace transform and compute the answer through an inverse Laplace transform.

Answer (score 3):

Hah! This is actually a specific example of something in my research! (My work attacks a more general set of integral equations, in some sense.) Let's go for something nontrivial (unlike previous answers/comments).

If you consider what I like to call a diagonal kernel, i.e. $g(x,t) = f(xt)$ for some $f$ and assume $g$ is real analytic, then this is very easily solvable. Since we want to get $\exp(-bx^4)$ after doing the integral, it stands to reason that $g$ should only consist of powers of the form $t^{4l}$.

Write $g(x,t) = \sum\limits_{l=0}^{\infty} c_l x^{4l} t^{4l}$, then we have

$$ e^{-bx^4} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} c_l x^{4l} t^{4l} e^{-at^4}\,dt.$$

Interchanging sum and limit (which can be justified after we compute what $c_l$ has to be by appealing to Fubini-Tonelli) this becomes

$$ e^{-bx^4} = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}2 c_l x^{4l} \int_0^{\infty} t^{4l}e^{-at^4}\,dt.$$

Letting $u = at^4$, $du = 4at^3\,dt$ so we have

$$ e^{-bx^4} = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}2 c_l x^{4l} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{4l}}{4at^3} e^{-u}\,du = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2a} c_l x^{4l} \int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{u}{a}\right)^{l-\frac{3}{4}} e^{-u}\,du.$$

The latter integral can be recognized as $\Gamma\left(l+\frac{1}{4}\right)$, yielding

$$ e^{-bx^4} = \frac{1}{2a^{\frac{1}{4}}}\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} a^{-l}c_l x^{4l} \Gamma\left(l+\frac{1}{4}\right). $$

Equating coefficients in the two power series gives that

$$ c_l = \frac{2(-1)^l a^{l+\frac{1}{4}}b^l}{l!\Gamma\left(l+\frac{1}{4}\right)}.$$

Plugging this back into $g$ we have

$$ g(x,t) = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \frac{2(-1)^la^{l+\frac{1}{4}}b^l}{l!\Gamma\left(l+\frac{1}{4}\right)} x^{4l}t^{4l}.$$

This looks pretty terrible, however it is not! This actually has a closed form solution in terms of a Bessel function:

$$ g(x,t) = 2 a^{\frac{5}{8}} b^{\frac{3}{8}} |xt|^{\frac{3}{2}} J_{-\frac{3}{4}}\left(2\sqrt{ab} x^2t^2\right). $$

What is nice is that if $a=b$, then you can use this to define a unitary integral transform (defined on a dense subspace of $L^2$ of course).

Comment: My constant factor out front is slightly off. I am fixing it now.

Comment: Thank you. Great answer. Can you point me to your research?

Comment: You can find my paper [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.4168) on arXiv, however it is not great (and very, very different from what was accepted to the journal), but the basic idea is contained therein.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Is your $g(x,t)$ integrable in one of the variables?

Comment: If you mean Lebesgue integrable over the whole real line, no. It is highly oscillatory and blows up at infinity. The integral diverges.

Comment: I see. Are you aware of any integrable solutions?

Comment: There is but I don't know what it is off the top of my head. It's connected to another part of my research which has yet to be published.

Comment: Great. Could you update the question once you have it. I will be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. Just in case anyone is curious, I verified numerically that this solution works (via numerical integration) for various values of $a$, $b$, and $x$.

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution can be obtained by making $g(x,t)$ degenerate:
$$
g(x,t)={1\over2}\exp(-bx^4)\exp(at^4-|t|)
$$
which is susceptible to the generalization
$$
g(x,t)={1\over C}\exp(-bx^4)\exp(at^4)f(t)
$$
where $f$ is integrable over $\mathbb R$ and
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)dt=C\neq0
$$

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware that the problem might have degenerate solutions. Thank you, I learned a lot from your example. What would be a non-generate solution to such a problem?

Comment: @Boby John Barber's comment on your post provides a non-degenerate solution.

Comment: You mean a delta function? I would like one in terms of continuous function.

Comment: @Boby Yes although it doesn't meet your continuity criterion.

Comment: Yes, but delta 'function' is not really a function in a classical sense